# Arduino shield - what should I solder to the pin mounts?

Tags: arduino

Picked up my first Arduino shield today and I was surprised to see that it doesn't have any pins on it - just empty mount holes.  What's the cusomary thing to solder to the shield to get it to mount to my arduino?  From what I understand these shields should be stackable so I need to solder something to both the top and bottom sides of the shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sparkfun has a handy package: [Arduino Stackable Header Kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10007).

For the actual Arduino itself, you would use these [0.100" breakaway female headers](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/115)